# How to retrieve the "element's id" of the previous element to become the "innerText" of the current element by startup/onLoad?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Want to pass the "element's id" of the previous element to become the "innerText" of the current element by startup/onLoad. I don't know. The point is it must be loaded or started since the beginning start when I clicked to open the PopUp. Don't ask why but the condition force me to achieve this. Look I'll to describing this as clear as I can I hope you'll be understand easly.

the first I create the code of some line at .gs file (GAS). the path was likes this:

======================= **The client side server on gs file** =======================

```
.....
var s = SpreadsheetApp,
    ss = s.getActiveSpreadsheet(),
    sss = ss.getSheets();
.....
  for (var i=0, iLen=sss.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    result += "<tr>";
    result += "<td id='"+sss[i].getName().replace(/\(/g,'<').replace(/\)/g,'>')+"'></td>";
    result += "<td contentEditable='true' onLoad='this.innerText=this.previousElementSibling.id'></td>";
    result += "<td>X</td>";
    result += "</tr>";
.....
```

Now the path what I mean there is in of "**onLoad='this.innerText=this.previousElementSibling.id'**". it doesn't work. What should I do wtih this? because if I put the code like this "***...>"+sss[i].getName().replace(/(/g,'<').replace(/)/g,'>')+"</td>***" there will be bugs there will come.
and I attach the pic too to give more the explanation. Please some lighten for me and any help will be so appreciated and sorry my typing (english) is not good.

[image]

Comment: Sorry the 1st column and and the 3rd column has been hiding by CSS line so it's just the path for the example I was to made a describe it shortly. The problem always comes out after I adding the looping name of sheets and then wont to display a name of every each by completely thats why I want create this with another way. Anyone whos can tell why and how to solve this?

Comment: No, I have to sorry because my english too. well I'm trying to answer them.
1. I want to display the names of sheet loading at startup means when the popup is open.
2. it's doesn't work because its still nothing happen at all. no result. its blank name of cames out (zero means nothing).
3. there will be bugs there will come if I put the diferent code of my achievement on any line at <td ......>"+sss[i].getName().replace(/(/g,'<').replace(/)/g,'>')+"</td> looks at my pic I've attached.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. From your replying, I understood that you want to retrieve the sheet names and put them to a HTML table on a dialog of Spreadsheet. Is my understanding correct? If my understanding is correct, about the sheet names, are there the limitations you want to give?

Comment: Yes, you are correct @Tanaike. Glad to hear it that you've understand it.
And Yes I want to give some rules or pattern by replacement of bracket("(" and ")") by less then sign "<" and greater then sign ">".

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your sample image, about `(DBS`)`, what do you want to do? By the way, I cannot understand about `And Yes I want to give some rules or pattern by replacement of bracket("(" and ")") by less then sign "<" and greater then sign ">".`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: About `<td>X</td>`, what do you want to do?

Comment: That path of name it doesn't shown at dialog or popup as properly as the original name but by replacing by the pattern I given its look likes have been removed by system I don't know why even thought I don't expected this @Tanaike

Comment: for example : every single name of sheet must be shown at the dialog and by the condition I given of the replacement. e.g:
(1) first name of sheet (DB) >>>> <1> first name of sheet <DB>
(2) second name of sheet (OUT) >>>> <2> second name of sheet <OUT>
and so on and on ...

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, I couldn't understand about your replying. I have 3 questions now. 1. From your sample image, about `(DBS)`, what do you want to do? 2. About `And Yes I want to give some rules or pattern by replacement of bracket("(" and ")") by less then sign "<" and greater then sign ">".`.`, can I ask you about the detail of it? 3. `<td>X</td>` is `path of name`? If it's so, can I ask you about `path of name`?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. About your replying, I cannot understand about `every single name of sheet must be shown at the dialog and by the condition I given of the replacement. e.g: (1) first name of sheet (DB) >>>> <1> first name of sheet <DB> (2) second name of sheet (OUT) >>>> <2> second name of sheet <OUT> and so on and on`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: Please add a [mcve].

Comment: @DebyFerdian I'm glad that your issue was solved, thanks for sharing that and your nice words. Please bear in mind that here the questions aren't "closed" when the issue if solved, you can still improve your question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry it take me so long to me to get the solved this by my self. I **chouldn't use attribute of onload** through on an element. However I using the **window.onload** and put this code directly into the script's tag instead of it and it's work very nice and all fine because the names all has suceed out as I expected. See the down below this of my expectation output:

[image]

**=============================== And the code was: ============================**

```
.....
var s = SpreadsheetApp,
    ss = s.getActiveSpreadsheet(),
    sss = ss.getSheets(),
    result = "<head><script type='text/javascript'>function swapNme() {",
    result += "var trs = document.querySelectorAll('tr');",
    result += "  for (var i=0, iLen=trs.length; i<iLen; i++) {",
    result += "    trs[i].children[1].innerText = trs[i].children[0].id;",
    result += "   };",
    result += " };",
    result += "window.onload=swapNme;",
.....
    result += "</script></head><table>";
.....
  for (var i=0, iLen=sss.length; i<iLen; i++) {
var result += "<tr>";
    result += "<td id='"+sss[i].getName().replace(/\(/g,'<').replace(/\)/g,'>')+"' class='hidden'></td>";
    result += "<td contentEditable='true'></td>";
    result += "<td class='hidden'>X</td>";
    result += "</tr>";
.....
```